# O=(N²) slower when executed ten times?

Tags: big-o

I have two for loops which means I have O=(N²). 
So if N is 5000 it would be, 25000000(if it's executed once). If I execute it once this is correct but if I execute it 10 times, it takes much more steps. Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big-O notation is for describing the asymptotic number of steps of algorithms. It is for comparing different algorithm for large inputs. For instance *heap sort* and *merge sort* are in *O*(*n* log *n*). Thus, they are asymptotically *faster* than *insertion sort* which is in *O*(*n*^2).

Running the same algorithm a constant number doesn't change its complexity, and the big-O class is just an estimation and not an exact measure for the number of steps. Thus, saying your algorithm needs 25,000,000 steps must not be correct (e. g. *n*(*n* - 1) / 1,000,000 is in *O*(*n*^2), too).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After reading your answer I found what was wrong with my code.